# I am trying to find a story that I read online some time ago. (uploading, similar to "Accelerando", "natural reserve" for humans)

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi, online-resources

This is what I remember:

- I think the author was not a professional writer but the story was cited in other webs.
- A main theme was "uploading".
- The pace remembered me to "Accelerando" by Charles Stross: it covers a time period between the near future and the far future.
- The main character have fallen to a "town" that is surrounded by walls where there is a landscape painted. It is a kind of "natural reserve" for humans. I think this is the first part of the story.
- The civilization out of the "natural reserve" was not very human friendly and the humans in there didn't know about outside.
- The main character was the first uploaded person. The story explains how he makes profit from this initially and how the different copies of him interact.
- I think that, at some point, there are two characters called Alpha and Omega.

Comment: Can I suggest changing the title of this question to something more specific? There are a lot of questions with titles like "Which story is this?" :-)

Comment: good suggestion, I'm going to try.

Comment: This sounds like a mixture of Tron and The Truman Show... I'm pretty sure you're going to need to add some more specific information before anyone can help you.

Comment: I don't think it is the same story, but there are some parallels with a story I wrote (A first draft of) called Web Portal http://dampes8n.deviantart.com/art/Web-Portal-123498206 A lot of the details are similar. Enough that I should mention it. No Alpha/Omega though.

Comment: Not the one you are looking for, but another good story that deals with uploading is Peter Hamilton's "Second Chance at Eden"

Comment: I found it so, I am going to answer to my own question. Thanks to everybody for trying.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a novella called "After Life" by Simon Funk, and is [available online](http://sifter.org/~simon/AfterLife/index.html).

The text is longer than I remembered. Indeed, the main theme is uploading. At some point of the novella there are three characters called: "alpha", "beta" and "omega". They appear for a short time.

Currently a link to the novella appears in [the Wikipedia page for "technological singularity"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technological_singularity#Fiction).